# Line removal from an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, line

I have used Hough Transforms to detect straight lines in an image. `houghlines` function returns line endpoints which one can plot. However i wish to remove the detected line from the image by creating a black line on the image of pixel width Two.

Here is a sample plot of Hough line onto the image.
[image]

This is a sample output. I want to set all the green pixels to zero. I have already tried using this [Bresenham](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28190-bresenham-optimized-for-matlab) code to get all the points between two end points of the line and setting them to zero. However the results are not as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is different possible approaches to do so. A very simple approach is to use [im2bw](http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html) to set a threshold.

```
I = imread('fH7ha.jpg');

figure;
subplot 121; imshow(I); title('before')

I = rgb2gray(I);
I = im2bw(I, 0.9);

subplot 122; imshow(I); title('after')
```

The result is:
[image]

However this is a bit inaccurate since some part of the line are outside of your image, you can then isolate the green area and dilate it using [imdilate](http://au.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html):

```
I = imread('fH7ha.jpg');

figure;
subplot 131; imshow(I); title('before')

green_pixels = I(:,:,2)-I(:,:,1)-I(:,:,3);
green_pixels = im2bw(green_pixels, 0.1);
se = strel('disk', 2);
green_pixels = imdilate(green_pixels, se);

subplot 132; imshow(green_pixels); title('green pixels')

I = rgb2gray(I);
I(green_pixels) = 0;

subplot 133; imshow(I); title('after')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I appreciate it. However this is not what i wanted to do. Since the green line is not a part of the original image, but a line plot over the image. Thus i want to remove that very line that you removed but without using green color for doing it. I just want have the endpoints of the green line.

Comment: You mean `lines = houghlines(...); xy = [lines(1).point1; lines(1).point2];`? o_0

Comment: Yes. Thats what i have

Comment: @harjatin, so what are you after. I'm not sure to follow

Comment: I have the line end points. And i can plot it(example the green line here). I just want to find a way to remove(set value=0) the pixels that fall on that line(the green one). I tried getting all the points on the line using bresenham and then remove them. However that does not remove all the pixels that are covered by the green line.

Comment: Well, then you can use imdilate from the output from Bresenham, no? I guess that should do the job.

Comment: I tried that. It does not do the expected job. I expected it to remove all the pixels that are green here. :(

Comment: Can you edit your code and share what you tried so far?

Comment: Yes. Sure. I just got the points from the bresenham link mentioned in the question and for every point, made the corresponding pixel's value to zero.

Comment: Well, share the original image, share the code, show the unsatisfactory results and why it is not good.